# Is there any beautifulsoup function to select duplicate class names?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There are two classes in my website, first, let's say `wikitable something` and second let's say `wikitable`.

I am trying to select the second class (`wikitable`) using the code `soup.find('table',class_='wikitable')` but all I am geting is the first class.

Comment: `find()` just finds the first match, use `findall()`.

Comment: @Barmar It is a good point, but this will also get both tables and not only the table with the class name `wikitable`

Comment: `wikitable something` are **2** css classes qualifying 1 tag.

Answer (score 2):

You already used the term in your question - use strict conditions like `select("table[class='wikitable']")`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table class="wikitable something"></table>
<table class="wikitable"></table>
"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

tables = soup.select("table[class='wikitable']")
print(tables)
```

**Output**

```
[<table class="wikitable"></table>]
```

**Addition**
If there is only one table that contains the single class name wikitable you can use also `soup.select_one("table[class='wikitable']")`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `:not()` selector to exclude the other class.

```
wikitable = soup.select('table.wikitable:not(.something)')[0]
```

Comment: Hot stuff - Never heard of that before, but a very cool way to work with excludes.

Answer (score 0):

To select the second `wikitable` class, try using a CSS Selector: `.class-name:nth-of-type(n)`.

For example:

```
print(soup.select_one('.wikitable:nth-of-type(2)'))
```